# selectMany in functional LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var collecion = new List<List<ToTest>>
                    {
                        new List<ToTest>{new ToTest {Id = 1, Name = "some name"}, new ToTest {Id = 4, Name = "some name2"}},
                        new List<ToTest>{new ToTest {Id = 2, Name = "some name"}, new ToTest {Id = 5, Name = "some name2"}},
                        new List<ToTest>{new ToTest {Id = 3, Name = "some name"}, new ToTest {Id = 6, Name = "some name2"}},
                    };
```

i want to use functional linq instead of lambda linq

```
    var result1 = collecion.SelectMany(q => q).ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: What is functional LINQ?

Comment: Using the linq extensions methods is the "functional" way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var result1 = from collection in collections
              from item in collection
              select item;
```

Comment: make some more efforts and provide little bit more info, because right now your answer is showing under the head "low quality".

Comment: @RobinHood - The answer is short, sweet, and answers the OP's question exactly. If the answer is flagged as Low Quality, then there's an issue with the flagging algorithm.